# GSM7 bit padding for SMS concatenation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sms, bit-manipulation, smpp

I'm writing an algorithm for splitting large SMS messages(>140 bytes) into smaller parts(140 bytes) in order to be able to send them to mobile operators via SMPP protocol.

Each part has an UDH(User Data Header) consisting of 6 or 7 bytes. The documentation I used for this is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/

So the structure of a message part will be:

[UDH][PART_BODY] where

[UDH] - 6 or 7 bytes

[PART_BODY] - 133 or 134 bytes

Also, each of the sources above mention that, if GSM7 encoding is used, padding bits should be added at the beginning of the part body to ensure that the part body will start on a septet boundary.

This is where I start to get confused... While I understood how septets are stored in a byte and what padding  means, I don't understand how to implement this in my actual code that looks like this:

```
public void AddUDHToSmSend(ref SMSend Sm, byte[] Udh)
{           
    byte[] msg = new byte[Udh.Length + Sm.Message.Length];
    Udh.CopyTo(msg, 0);
    Sm.Message.CopyTo(msg, Udh.Length);
    Sm.Message = msg;       
}
```

Udh - an array of bytes

Sm.Message - an array of bytes representing the part body

How can I add a padding bit in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: How _do_ you expect septets to be stored in a byte?  Packed (i.e: you can store 8 septets in 7 bytes), or one septet per byte with the high bit ignored?

Comment: Hi. They should be packed. Thx

Comment: @Florin Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

So unless the Sm.message class is doing the bit packing, you are going to need to implement it yourself.

Something like this (pseudo-c#):

```
class Bitpacker {
    Bitpacker(Byte* buffer, int size) {
        mBuf = buffer;
        mSize = size;
        mLen=0;
        mOffset=0;
    }

   int pack(Byte val, int nbits) {
      val&=(1<<nbits)-1; //restrict to `nbits` bits
      mBuf[mLen]|= val<<mOffset;
      mOffset+=nbits;
      if (mOffset>=8) {
         mBuf[mLen++]|= val>>(8-nbits);
         mOffset-=8;
      }
      return mLen;  //todo - check that mLen !=size;
   }
}
```

Then you can use this class to pack first the header, then the padding, then the body.

```
foreach octet in header {
    packer.pack(octet,8);
    bitcount+=8;
}
padbits = bitcount%7;
packer.pack(0,padbits);
foreach septet in body {
    packer.pack(septet,7);
}
```